# Не пойму где ошибка в коде

Tags: c++, массивы

Не могу понять в чем ошибка:

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF7168D2679 в project 7.exe:
> 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу
> 0x0000025FB9C35000.

```
   int Maximum(int** arr, int n, int m){

    int max = arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < m; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Условие `i < m` во вложенном цикле не зависит от счётчика цикла `j`. Следовательно цикл не остановится, следовательно выход за границы массива. Заменить на `j < m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка повсей видимости здесь:

```
// У Вас
for (int j = 0; i < m; j++)

// А должно быть
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
```